# DXL to display a word based on the condition of a linked attribute

Tags: ibm-doors

I am a DXL newbie and am trying to use layout DXL in Module_X to display a text output based on the the value of a linked attribute in Module_Y.

Module_X has multiple out-links, one of which it is Module_Y. The attribute I want to read from Module_Y is called Version_number and is a range of enumerations from "Version 1" to "Version 6".

If the linked version is greater than Version 3 then I would like to output a 'Yes' text string in the layout DXL that this run in within Module_X.
Each object in Module_X may have more than one linked version_number. There are 5 hops in total between Module_X and Module_Y.

I have attempted to do this via the Analysis Wizard to display the linked version_number attribute, which is successful.
However I am unsure how to approach the "if the value of version_number contains > Version_3" element.
Any help appreciated, please let me know if I need to break this question down a bit.

```
void showOut(Object o, int depth) {
Link l
LinkRef lr
ModName_ otherMod = null
Module linkMod = null
ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
Object othero
string disp = null
string s = null
string plain, plainDisp
int plainTextLen
int count
bool doneOne = false
string linkModName = "*"
for l in all(o->linkModName) do {
    otherVersion = targetVersion l
    otherMod = module(otherVersion)
    if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
    if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[depth-1]))) continue
    if (versionString(otherVersion) != limitVersions[depth-1]) continue
    othero = target l
    if (null othero) {
        load(otherVersion,false)
    }
    othero = target l
    if (null othero) continue
    if (isDeleted othero) continue
    int oldLines = lines[depth-1]
    adjustLines(depth, 4)
    bool kick = (doneOne) && (lines[depth-1] == oldLines)
    if (kick) {
        lines[depth-1]++
        if (depth == 4) displayRich("\\pard " " ")
    }
    if (depth < 4) {
        showOut(othero, depth+1)
    }
    doneOne = true
    if (depth == 4) {
        s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Version_number", false)

        if (s == "") 
        displayRich("\\pard " " ")
        else
        displayRich("\\pard " s)
    }
    lines[depth-1] += 1
}
```

}
showOut(obj,1)

Comment: please post the code generated by the Analysis wizard. It is then easier to point out the needed changes.

Comment: Thanks, have added code as advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Version_number", false)

    if (s == "") 
    displayRich("\\pard " " ")
    elseif(intOf(s[8])>3)
    displayRich("\\pard " s)
```

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani How is this a 'link-only answer'? Please pay attention when reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. In the end as it happens, the 'link only' part wasnt relevent due to a change in the task so this code worked a treat.

Many thanks :-)